# IBM Watson URL rebuild function XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint, watson

I'm currently using IBM Watson Foundational Components in combination with Sharepoint servers.

The biggest issue seems to be the handling of managed paths, where Watson rebuilds the original URL into its own format. The conversion is done with the following code.

```
      <xsl:variable name="url-tokens" select="str:tokenize($seed-urls, '&#10;')" />
      <xsl:variable name="fixed-urls">

        <!-- &#10; == newline -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$url-tokens">
          <xsl:variable name="url-parts" select="viv:url-decompose(.)" />
          <!-- Append a slash ("/") to the path, unless the path already has a slash, or ends in ".aspx" -->
          <xsl:variable name="fixed-path" select="concat($url-parts/path,viv:if-else(viv:match($url-parts/path, '(\.aspx|\/)$'),'','/'))" />

          <!-- Rebuild the URL, but use the io-sp protocol and the fixed path (constructed above) -->

          <xsl:value-of select="viv:url-build($crawl-protocol, '', '', $url-parts/host, $url-parts/port, $fixed-path, '')" />
          <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
```

e.g. www.sharepoint-domain.com/IT/PM/page_name is decomposed in the following bits:

- host : www.sharepoint-domain.com
- path : IT/PM/page_name

This decomposition is then rebuilt with the following structure:

-> www.sharepoint-domain.com/site/GUID_of_page_name

What we want to do, is change the result of the decomposition to the following:

- host : www.sharepoint-domain.com/IT/PM/
- path : page_name

Is there a way change the value of host and path with the use of XSL 1.0?
In such a way that *IT/PM/* does not belong to path but to host.

**Ps:** viv:url-decompose(.) creates from $url-parts :

- $url-parts/host
- $url-parts/port
- $url-parts/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible, Those values are immutable.

**But** you name the original url-parts and create your own valules ...

**Thus**

First of all, name the first decompose differently:

```
<xsl:variable name="url-parts-temp" select="viv:url-decompose(.)" />
```

Secondly, create a variable *url* together with it belonging values:

```
<xsl:variable name="url">
    <path><xsl:value-of select="substring($url-parts-temp/path,string-length('it/pm')+2)"/></path>
    <host><xsl:value-of select="concat($url-parts-temp/host,$url-parts-temp/path)"/></host>
    <port>$url-parts-temp/port</port>
    <query>$url-parts-temp/query</query>
</xsl:variable>
```

Thirdly, use **exsl:node-set** regarding to the variable *$url*:

```
<xsl:variable name="url-parts" select="exsl:node-set($url)" />
```

**Result** now you can use url-parts, just like before:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$url-parts/host" />
<xsl:value-of select="$url-parts/path" />
```